# Showing $X^*$ is separable implies $X$ is separable using the Riesz lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces, separable-spaces

> If $X$ is a Banach space and $X^*$ is separable, then $X$ is
>   separable.

[Here, David Mitra mentions a proof using the Riesz lemma.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106961/separability-of-banach-spaces) However, I do not fully understand it.

> You could also use Riesz' lemma:
>
> Let $Y$ be a  proper closed subspace of the normed space $X$ and
>   $0<\theta<1$. Then there is an $x_\theta$ of norm 1 for which $\Vert
>  x_\theta-y\Vert>\theta$ for all $y\in Y$.
>
> If $X$ were not seperable, you could use Hahn Banach to   construct
>   uncountably many functionals $f_\alpha\in X^*$ with  $\Vert
>  f_\alpha-f_\beta\Vert\ge \theta$ whenever $\alpha\ne\beta$.

If $X$ is not separable, why does that allow us to construct uncountably many separated functionals $f_\alpha$?

I see why this fact would imply the theorem. Taking a countable dense set and $\epsilon$ balls around each point in that set, we see that two elements of the uncountable set $\{ f_\alpha\}$ must lie in a single ball. But then they are at most $2\epsilon$ apart. Making $\epsilon$ small shows we can find two elements of the set less than $\theta$ apart, a contradiction.

Comment: I made a mistake in the earlier version of my proof: I erroneously claimed that $\overline {X_{\alpha}}$ is a proper closed sub**space** instead of a proper closed sub**set**. Sorry about this careless error. I corrected this by considering spans. Please make sure to consult the correct version.

Comment: @triple_sec Thank you!

Comment: It's actually fairly easy by an argument that has nothing to do with the Riesz Lemma. See new answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is not separable and fix $\theta\in(0,1)$. Let $\Omega$ be the set of countable ordinals. Fix $\alpha\in\Omega$ and using transfinite induction, suppose that $x_{\beta}\in X$ and $f_{\beta}\in X^*$ have already been defined for all $\beta\in\Omega$ such that $\beta<\alpha$ (if $\alpha=\min\Omega$, simply define $x_{\alpha}\equiv0$ and $f_{\alpha}\equiv 0$).

Let $$X_{\alpha}\equiv\{x_{\beta}\,|\,\beta\in\Omega,\,\beta<\alpha\}.$$
Since $X_{\alpha}$ is countable and $X$ is not separable, it follows that $Y_{\alpha}\equiv\overline{\operatorname{span}X_{\alpha}}$ is a *proper* closed subspace (I will prove this at the end of the post). Pick any $x_{\alpha}\in X\setminus Y_{\alpha}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\|x_{\alpha}\|=&\,1,\\
\inf_{y\in Y_{\alpha}}\|x_{\alpha}-y\|\geq&\,\theta,
\end{align*} which is possible by Riesz's lemma. Now, using the Hahn—Banach theorem, there exists $f_{\alpha}\in X^*$ such that
\begin{align*}f_{\alpha}(y)=&\,0\quad\forall y\in Y_{\alpha},\\
\|f_{\alpha}\|=&\,1,\\
f_{\alpha}(x_{\alpha})=&\,\inf_{y\in Y_{\alpha}}\|x_{\alpha}-y\|\geq\theta;
\end{align*}
see, for example, Theorem 5.8(a) in [Folland (1999, p. 159)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160).

Now, the family $\{f_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in\Omega}$ is uncountable (given that $\Omega$ is uncountable and, as the next argument will reveal, $f_{\alpha}$ and $f_{\beta}$ are distinct for distinct $\alpha,\beta\in\Omega$). Suppose that $\alpha,\beta\in\Omega$ and $\alpha\neq\beta$. Without loss of generality, assume that $\beta<\alpha$. Then, $x_{\beta}\in X_{\alpha}\subseteq Y_{\alpha}$, so $f_{\alpha}(x_{\beta})=0$. Also, $f_{\beta}(x_{\beta})\geq\theta$. Therefore, $$\|f_{\alpha}-f_{\beta}\|=\sup_{\substack{x\in X\\\|x\|\leq1}}|f_{\alpha}(x)-f_{\beta}(x)|\geq|f_{\alpha}(x_{\beta})-f_{\beta}(x_{\beta})|\geq\theta.$$

---

The following claim reveals that if $X$ is not separable, then the subspace $\operatorname{span} X_{\alpha}$ is not dense for any $\alpha\in\Omega$.

> **Claim:** If $C\equiv\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}\subseteq X$ is a countable subset and $\operatorname{span}C$ is a dense subspace, then $X$ is separable.

*Proof:* Let $\mathbb S$ be a countable dense subset of the underlying field ($\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, presumably). Define, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, $$L_n\equiv\{q_1 x_1+\ldots+q_n x_n\,|\,q_1,\ldots,q_n\in\mathbb S\}$$ and $L\equiv\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} L_n$. It is easy to see that $L$ is countable.

I claim that $L$ is dense. To see this, pick any $x\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\operatorname{span} C$ is dense, there exist some $n\in\mathbb N$ and members of the underlying field $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ such that $$\left\|x-\sum_{m=1}^np_mx_m\right\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$ Now, for each $m\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$, pick $q_m\in\mathbb S$ such that $$|p_m-q_m|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2n(\|x_m\|+1)}.$$ Then, $y\equiv\sum_{m=1}^n q_m x_m\in L$ and $$\|x-y\|\leq\left\|x-\sum_{m=1}^np_mx_m\right\|+\left\|\sum_{m=1}^n(p_m-q_m)x_m\right\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\sum_{m=1}^n|p_m-q_m|\|x_m\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.$$ Hence, $x\in\overline{L}$ and the proof is complete. $\quad\blacksquare$

Answer (score 6):

Here is my favorite proof, which I think is simpler than both the one suggested by David C. Ullrich and the one I had given earlier, elaborating on David Mitra’s hint. It uses only the Hahn–Banach theorem, but not Riesz’s lemma. It is based on the hint presented in Exercise 5.25, [Folland (1999, p. 160)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160).

If $X^*$ is separable, let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a countable dense subset of it. By the definition of the operator norm $$\|f_n\|\equiv\sup_{\substack{x\in X\\\|x\|\leq 1}}|f_n(x)|,$$ it is possible, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, to choose some $x_n\in X$ such that $\|x_n\|\leq 1$ and $$|f_n(x_n)|\geq\frac{1}{2}\|f_n\|\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ (if $f_n=0$, then simply choose $x_n=0$; if $\|f_n\|>0$, use the definition of the supremum).

Let $C\equiv\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$. I claim that $\operatorname{span} C$ is dense, which implies that $X$ is separable (see the last claim in my previous post). To see this, suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $\operatorname{span} C$ is not dense; then $Y\equiv\overline{\operatorname{span} C}$ is a proper closed subspace. By the Hahn–Banach theorem, it is possible to choose $f\in X^*$ such that
\begin{align*}
f(y)=&\,0\quad\forall y\in Y,\\
\|f\|=&\,1;
\end{align*}
see again Theorem 5.8(a) in [Folland (1999, p. 159)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160). Since $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is dense in $X^*$, there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\|f_n-f\|< 1/3$. But then
\begin{align*}
|f_n(x_n)|=|f_n(x_n)-\underbrace{f(x_n)}_{=0}|\leq\|f_n-f\|<\frac{1}{3},\tag{$\diamondsuit$}
\end{align*}
whereas
\begin{align*}
1=\|f\|\leq\|f-f_n\|+\|f_n\|<\frac{1}{3}+\|f_n\|,
\end{align*}
so that $\|f_n\|>2/3$. Putting this into ($\diamondsuit$),
$$|f_n(x_n)|<\frac{1}{3}<\frac{1}{2}\|f_n\|,$$ which contradicts ($\clubsuit$).

Answer (score 3):

Third version - maybe this one is right.

Lemma. If $K$ is a separable compact Hausdorff space then $C(K)$ is separable. (And it follows that $K$ is metrizable, but we won't be using that.)

Proof. Wlog $K$ is infinite. Say $p_1,\dots$ are dense, $p_j\ne p_k$ for $j\ne k$. Choose  $f_{j,k}:K\to\Bbb R$, such that $f_{j,k}(p_j)\ne f_{j,k}(p_k)$. The algebra generated by $1$ and the $f_{j,k}$ is separable, and Stone-Weierstrass shows it's dense in $C(K)$.

Now suppose $X^*$ is separable, and let $K$ be the closed unit ball of $X^*$ with the weak* topology. The lemma implies that $C(K)$ is separable.

But the map $x\mapsto f_x$, where $f_x(x^*)=x^*(x)$, is an isometry from $X$ into $C(K)$. So $X$ is separable.

Comment: Wow. This is much better than the proofs in the other question.

Comment: @Potato Yeah. Wouldn't have thought of such a thing, if not for the Banach space guy in the department who reminds us once every few years that every Banach space is (isometrically) a subspace of $C(K)$ for some $K$...

Comment: @Potato Oops. See edit. Was such a nice little argument. Lemme know if you can prove a separable compact Hausdorff space must be metrizable...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74923/a-compact-hausdorff-space-that-is-not-metrizable/75495#75495

Comment: @Potato Fixed it, I hope...

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thanks for the link. The topic is certainly relevant, but I don't see anything there that specifically helps here. If I'm missing something please advise. (Also lemme know that the current version of my answer is nonsense if it is...)

Comment: I'm sorry but this is actually not true: there are compact Hausdorff spaces which are separable but not metrizable, like the so-called split interval.