# $X^*$ is separable then $X$ is separable [Proof explanation]

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, hahn-banach-theorem

$X^*$ is separable then $X$ is separable
**Proof:**

Here is my favorite proof, which I think is simpler than both the one suggested by David C. Ullrich and the one I had given earlier, elaborating on David Mitra’s hint. It uses only the Hahn–Banach theorem, but not Riesz’s lemma. It is based on the hint presented in Exercise 5.25, [Folland (1999, p. 160)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471317160).

If $X^*$ is separable, let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a countable dense subset of it. By the definition of the operator norm $$\|f_n\|\equiv\sup_{\substack{x\in X\\\|x\|\leq 1}}|f_n(x)|,$$ it is possible, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, to choose some $x_n\in X$ such that $\|x_n\|\leq 1$ and $$|f_n(x_n)|\geq\frac{1}{2}\|f_n\|\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ (if $f_n=0$, then simply choose $x_n=0$; if $\|f_n\|>0$, use the definition of the supremum).

Let $C\equiv\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$. I claim that $\operatorname{span} C$ is dense, which implies that $X$ is separable (see the last claim in my previous post). To see this, suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $\operatorname{span} C$ is not dense; then $Y\equiv\overline{\operatorname{span} C}$ is a proper closed subspace. By the Hahn–Banach theorem, it is possible to choose $f\in X^*$ such that
\begin{align*}
f(y)=&\,0\quad\forall y\in Y,\\
\|f\|=&\,1;
\end{align*}
see again Theorem 5.8(a) in [Folland (1999, p. 159)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471317160). Since $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is dense in $X^*$, there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\|f_n-f\|< 1/3$. But then
\begin{align*}
|f_n(x_n)|=|f_n(x_n)-\underbrace{f(x_n)}_{=0}|\leq\|f_n-f\|<\frac{1}{3},\tag{$\diamondsuit$}
\end{align*}
whereas
\begin{align*}
1=\|f\|\leq\|f-f_n\|+\|f_n\|<\frac{1}{3}+\|f_n\|,
\end{align*}
so that $\|f_n\|>2/3$. Putting this into ($\diamondsuit$),
$$|f_n(x_n)|<\frac{1}{3}<\frac{1}{2}\|f_n\|,$$ which contradicts ($\clubsuit$).

> I don't understand the part apply Hahn Banach Theorem. This part in special:
>
> $\begin{align*}
> f(y)=&\,0\quad\forall y\in Y,\\
> \|f\|=&\,1;
> \end{align*}$

Can someone clarify me that part in special? Thanks for answer!

The answer is of this post: [Showing $X^*$ is separable implies $X$ is separable using the Riesz lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397622/showing-x-is-separable-implies-x-is-separable-using-the-riesz-lemma)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a bounded linear functional $f \in Y^{\ast}$ s.t. $f\vert_Y = 0$. Then choose some $u \in X \setminus Y$ with $\Vert u \Vert = 1$ (which exists since $Y$ is proper), define $g \in (Y \oplus \mathbb{C}u)^{\ast}$ via $g(u) = 1$ and $g\vert_Y = f$ and extend linearly.

Then we have $\Vert g \Vert = 1$, since for every $x \in X$ with $\Vert x \Vert = 1$ we either have $g(x) = 1$ or $g(x) = 0$. Hence Hahn-Banach gives an extension $G \in X^{\ast}$ s.t. $\Vert G \Vert = \Vert g \Vert = 1$ and $G \vert_Y = g \vert_Y = f = 0$.

---

The above uses the norm preserving version of Hahn-Banach. But really, you only need any extension of the above defined $g$. Then you can you may rescale, and since $g\vert_Y = 0$, the rescaled $g$ is also $0$ on $Y$. The sublinear functional used for this would be $x \mapsto \Vert g \Vert \cdot \Vert x \Vert$.

Comment: What is for you $\mathbb{C}u$ ? thanks for your answer

Comment: The subspace spaned by $u$. Maybe the notation $\langle u \rangle$ is more standard.

Answer (score 1):

Take $u\in X\setminus Y$ and define $f:Y\oplus \langle u\rangle\to \mathbb F$ by $f(y+cu)=c$. We can apply the Hahn-Banach theorem once we prove that $f$ is bounded. For this, use the fact that $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$ so that there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\|y-u\|>\delta$ for all $y\in Y.$ Then, the claim follows from the calculation $\|y+cu\|=|c|\cdot \left \|\left(\frac{-1}{c}\right)y-u\right \|>c\delta.$

Answer (score 1):

You only need the existence of a non-zero bounded linear functional on the quotient normed space $X/Y$, because composing it with the quotient map $X \rightarrow X/Y$ and then rescaling will give you the desired $f$.