# Does $X^\ast$ separable imply $X$ separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof: $X^\ast$ separable $\implies X$ separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82385/proof-x-ast-separable-implies-x-separable)

> Suppose $X$ is a normed vector space. Does $X^\ast$ separable imply $X$ separable?

If $X$ is complete, the answer is yes and this is well known. What about if we drop the completeness hypotesis? Is the statement still true? I'm a little puzzled... Thanks.

P.S. I find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82385/proof-x-ast-separable-implies-x-separable) question but it's not really the same thing, so I decided to open this new one.

Comment: Why isn't it the same thing?

Comment: In a separable metric space, any subset is separable. This is because a metric space is separable if and only if it possesses a countable basis of open sets. Given a subset you only need to intersect this basis with it to get a countable basis for the subset. In particular, if you can prove that the completion of $X$ is separable you'll get separability of $X$ for free.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo : the questions are very similar, I know. But I wasn't looking for a proof of this fact; if I'm not wrong, in the linked question a proof of this fact - when $X$ is a Banach space - is provided. I was simply looking for an answer to the question: "Is completeness necessary"? Indeed, Giuseppe Negro's comment answers completely to my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see where is the space is assumed complete in the link.

Comment: In t.b. answer, he wrote: "Always state what you assume! For instance, your choice of $Y$ later on indicates that you work with a real Banach space (who should know that this is assumed if you don't state it?)"